# Why in Eclipse I have not the autocomplete on the CSS attributes declared inline in my HTML?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, eclipse-mars

I have installed the Java SE version of **Eclipse Mars 2**, then I have installed the **WTP** tools for Java EE for the web development (or I think that I have download all these stuff but I am not so sure).

The problem is that if I write code into an html page, I can see the code syntax coloured according to the tab but I have not the code hints for the inline CSS.

So for example if I try to put some inline CSS on a tag I have the autocomplete function for the **style** attribute (if I write something like **st** on an html tag, pressing **CTRL + SPACE** Eclipse automatically write **style=""** for me) but I have not the autocomplete function for the inner CSS.

So for example if I write **style="margin-"** and the click **CTRL + SPACE** I have not the relative hints for the possible CSS attributes.

The strange thing is that if I open a **.css** file here the autocomplete function works fine.

What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does using Ctrl+Space work in a separate CSS file?

Comment: @BlakeNeal yes, into a .css file it works fine

Comment: I've run into this before too. Inline it doesn't, while it works in a separate CSS file. I'm pretty sure it has to do with filetype validation and help. (X)HTML files will give autocomplete help for (X)HTML content (like custom JSF namespaces (<p:dialog... />, for instance). CSS files will offer autocomplete for CSS files. Check out http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/782396/ for more information (although it isn't for Mars, it looks like an Eclipse ideology).